# How to import and run 3rd party Jenkins Plugin's extension DSL (githubPullRequest) with Gradle tool locally?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, gradle-plugin, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm a newbie  at Jenkins job-dsl scripting.

I'm working to convert the Jenkins XML configuration to Groovy DSL script using a plugin (https://github.com/AOEpeople/gradle-jenkins-job-dsl-plugin) that uses Gradle tool for building the script and running Unit Test locally.

However, currently, I'm facing an issue with the extension DSL from a 3rd Party Jenkins Plugin (https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin).

```
triggers {
    githubPullRequest {
         orgWhitelist("Test")
         cron("H/5 * * * *")
         extensions {
             commitStatus {
                 completedStatus('SUCCESS', 'Build succeeded.')
                 completedStatus('FAILURE', 'Build failed.')
             }
         }
     }
}
```

The script cannot be generated by Gradle because of the issue:

```
Expected no exception to be thrown, but got 'javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslScriptException'
at spock.lang.Specification.noExceptionThrown(Specification.java:119)
at com.aoe.gradle.jenkinsjobdsl.JobScriptsSpec.test DSL script #file.name(JobScriptsSpec.groovy:55)
Caused by: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslScriptException: (PullRequestJobTemplate.groovy, line 59) No signature of method: static org.apache.commons.lang.ClassUtils.isAssignable() is applicable for argument types: ([Ljava.lang.Class;, [Ljava.lang.Class;, java.lang.Boolean) values: [[class com.unified.dsl.templates.PullRequestJobTemplate$_closure1$_closure5$_closure15], ...]
Possible solutions: isAssignable([Ljava.lang.Class;, [Ljava.lang.Class;), isAssignable(java.lang.Class, java.lang.Class)
at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader.runScriptEngine(AbstractDslScriptLoader.groovy:107)
at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader.runScripts_closure1(AbstractDslScriptLoader.groovy:60)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader.runScripts(AbstractDslScriptLoader.groovy:46)
at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader.runScript(AbstractDslScriptLoader.groovy:81)
at com.aoe.gradle.jenkinsjobdsl.JobScriptsSpec.test DSL script #file.name(JobScriptsSpec.groovy:51)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static org.apache.commons.lang.ClassUtils.isAssignable() is applicable for argument types: ([Ljava.lang.Class;, [Ljava.lang.Class;, java.lang.Boolean) values: [[class com.unified.dsl.templates.PullRequestJobTemplate$_closure1$_closure5$_closure15], ...]
Possible solutions: isAssignable([Ljava.lang.Class;, [Ljava.lang.Class;), isAssignable(java.lang.Class, java.lang.Class)
at javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.ExtensionPointHelper.findExtensionPoints_closure1(ExtensionPointHelper.groovy:24)
at javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.ExtensionPointHelper.findExtensionPoints(ExtensionPointHelper.groovy:23)
at javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.JenkinsJobManagement.callExtension(JenkinsJobManagement.java:365)
at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractExtensibleContext.methodMissing(AbstractExtensibleContext.groovy:17)
at com.unified.dsl.templates.PullRequestJobTemplate.closure1$_closure5(PullRequestJobTemplate.groovy:59)
at com.unified.dsl.templates.PullRequestJobTemplate.closure1$_closure5(PullRequestJobTemplate.groovy)
at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.ContextHelper.executeInContext(ContextHelper.groovy:16)
at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.Job.triggers(Job.groovy:568)
at com.unified.dsl.templates.PullRequestJobTemplate$_closure1.doCall(PullRequestJobTemplate.groovy:58)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.JobParent.processItem(JobParent.groovy:114)
at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.JobParent.freeStyleJob(JobParent.groovy:47)
at com.unified.dsl.base.JobBuilder.build(JobBuilder.groovy:52)
at stage.script.run(script:12)
at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader.runScript(AbstractDslScriptLoader.groovy:124)
at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader.runScriptEngine(AbstractDslScriptLoader.groovy:101)
... 6 more
```

Comment: You need to add the plugin to your gradle build file

Comment: @RobKielty do you know how to add it? I'm also trying to figure out how to import the plugin (https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin) into build.gradle file. Please give me a guide if you have. Thanks

Comment: I have just tried with

    jenkinsPlugin 'org.jenkins-ci.plugins:ghprb:1.39.0' 

     Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jenkins-ci/plugins/ghprb/1.39.0/ghprb-1.39.0.pom
    Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/coravy/hudson/plugins/github/github/1.26.0/github-1.26.0.pom

I see it works well and download the plugin to local. However, still got the same issue.

Comment: Looking at this now. Hopefully an answer to follow

Comment: Are you showing line 59 of the script PullRequestJobTemplate.groovy in your question? That's where the problem is.

Comment: Added an answer. You're nearly there! Add the plugin dependencies and I'd say your test will run. If it does not work, please add your build file to the question and I will look at this again tomorrow. It's late here in GMT Good luck!

Comment: hi @RobKielty. I saw already the line 59 in my question, it's the line using `githubPullRequest`. Let me check your answer and get back to you. Thanks for your support here

Answer (score 1):

So the stacktrace you are getting is being generated by the Spock Test that checks to see if the job-dsl script compiles. So you have set up your development environment correctly! Always a good start.

Now all you need to do is setup your local Jenkins runtime to allow the Jenkins XML config file to be generated when it is kicked off by the Spock Test.

Reviewing your job-dsl script I must say it looks good to me. Specifically I compared it to the complete sample job-dsl on the GitHub pull request builder plugin's home page ...

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin#GitHubpullrequestbuilderplugin-JobDSLSupport

The key part of the stack trace is this line here

```
PullRequestJobTemplate.groovy, line 59) No signature of method: 
static org.apache.commons.lang.ClassUtils.isAssignable() is applicable 
for argument types: ([Ljava.lang.Class;, [Ljava.lang.Class;, 
java.lang.Boolean) values: [[class com.unified.dsl.templates.PullRequestJobTemplate$_closure1$_closure5$_closure15], ...]
```

To me this would indicate that there was still a run-time dependency missing to allow the GH PR Builder plugin job-dsl to run as expected.

Further reviewing the plugin page I note that the following dependencies are variously required and optional ...

```
credentials (version:1.21) 
matrix-project (version:1.6) 
build-flow-plugin (version:0.12, optional) 
ssh-agent (version:1.3) 
structs (version:1.6) 
github (version:1.26.0) 
git (version:2.4.0) 
github-api (version:1.82) 
plain-credentials (version:1.1) 
job-dsl (version:1.39, optional) 
token-macro (version:1.10, optional)
```

If you add these to the Gradle build then I would say that your XML will be generated.

Don't forget to add these dependencies to the target Jenkins server when you have completed your job-dsl development.

Comment: Hi @Rob Kielty, I tried to add the dependencies into gradle build file, I also see the gradle download when running `./gradlew build` command. However, the issue still be there.

Comment: Also, just found out other asked on the plugin github site https://github.com/janinko/ghprb/issues/411

Comment: Good work Tin. If you have all of the dependencies set up correctly and you still get this behaviour then you should post to the job-dsl and the gh pr plugin user groups and see if either Daniel or the GH maintainers can triage this as a bug.

Comment: If you can share your code I'll attempt to reproduce the problem and assist further.

Comment: Finally, I did a mock to pass the issue (see the solution at  github.com/janinko/ghprb/issues/411). I think dsl-job doesn't allow to use the extension dsl from Jenkins Plugin on Spock Test. Hopefully, they will support soon next time.

Comment: Thanks for your well-support Rob.