# How to run job-dsl-plugin locally with additional plugins

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

We are using the Jenkins Job-DSL plugin for creating a number of jobs and having the actual job-configuration as part of the version-controlled source-code.

In order to test the resulting XML files locally, I currently use something like the following:

```
java -jar /opt/job-dsl-plugin/job-dsl-core/build/libs/job-dsl-core-1.78-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar create_jobs.groovy
```

This allows to look at the resulting XML while making changes.

However some DSL elements are failing in the local build, but still work on the actual Jenkins installation.

E.g. "batchFile", "pullRequestBuildTrigger" and a few others.

As far as I understand these are separate Jenkins plugins which contribute some additional elements to the DSL, so the core job-dsl-plugin does not know about them.

I tried various ways of adding the code from these plugins to the job-dsl-plugin so that I can run the local transformation, but I could not find a way that actually works. Adding the plugins to job-dsl-plugin, classpath, ... nohting fixed it.

I also looked at [How to import and run 3rd party Jenkins Plugin's extension DSL (githubPullRequest) with Gradle tool locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46899830/), but the suggestions there did not work for me as I do not want to run a local Jenkins instance here.

So how can I run the job-dsl-plugin manually with DSL from additional plugins being available?